# File ownership in debian packages

Tags: debian

I just curious about managing file ownership in debian packages. How to preserve file ownership during building deb packages. I want a files own by a specific user when I install them.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `dh_fixperms`. Either don't run it or use `chown` after you call `dh_fixperms`. I guess that another way would be to run `chown` in postinst.